# How can I overwrite Laravel Service Container tagged concrete implementations in a test?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a single interface that has a single implementing class for now. In the Laravel Service Container I have tagged that concrete class against the interface.

```
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->tag([
            ConcreteClassA::class,
        ], Interface::class);
    }
```

I would like to overwrite that tag completely with a mocked implenentation of that interface. I've tried the following:

```
$mock = $this->mock(Interface::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('someMethod')
                ->andReturn(Carbon::now());
        });

app()->tag([$mock], Interface::class);
```

I have also used different variation of `binding()` and `instance()` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest using instance().

```
$this->app->instance(Interface::class, Mockery::mock(Interface::class, function($mock){
            $mock->shouldReceive("someMethod")->andReturn(Carbon::now());
        }));

$mocked = $this->app->make(Interface::class);
$mocked->someMethod()
```

You can also use the tag method, but then you'll have two concrete classes bound to an interface. eventually, if you resolved the interface by using make method, you'll get the second class which it's the mock class.